# Asymptotic properties of estimates

Tags: regression, time-series, maximum-likelihood, econometrics, asymptotics

How do the asymptotic properties of estimates depend on stationarity of time series (and other properties of underlying DGP, e.g., the distribution of errors)? For example, a lot of books and papers about asymptotics of MLE consider only the case of independent random variables (or vectors) or give a set of conditions which are hard to interpret and tell nothing about application of this theory to often used models. Can you give me any references to relevant literature or explain asymptotic properties of time series in short.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotic maximum likelihood estimation is claimed to be a [cross validation  equivalent technique](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~laan/Research/Research_subpages/.../likcrossvalf.pdf). Regardless, for time series, this is only a magnitude of goodness of fit criterion. It yields no information about how times series models extrapolate to non-interpolated times. Indeed, arbitrary models would generally do a poor job of extrapolation. For extrapolation, only models that fulfill multiple other conditions are useful, and such conditions are most typically ignored. If you would be so good as to specify more exactly what type of answer you are requesting, I may be able to give you more relevant information.